# typescript can i redefine T in Array<T> in interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I have an interface file like below.

I want to redefine the type Student using that interface.

```
export interface School{
    name: string;
    student: {
        student_id: number;
        student_name: string;
    }[];
}

type Student = ... (student_id: number, student_name)
```

So, I tried this:

```
type Student = Pick<School, "student">["student"]
==>
#Student = {
#   student_id: number;
#   student_name: string;
#}[]
```

But it is an array and not a generic array.

In that case, how can I define school object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I unfortunately don't understand what you mean by "redefine" or "generic array"... if the answers here don't meet your needs, please consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be more clear.   Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Student` type of school by [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `"student"` property of `School`, which is an array type, and then the `number` property of that array type, like this:

```
export interface School {
  name: string;
  student: {
    student_id: number;
    student_name: string;
  }[];
}

type Student = School["student"][number];
// type Student = {
//    student_id: number;
//    student_name: string;
// }
```

If the `number` is confusing to you, imagine you had a variable `school` of type `School`, a variable `studentKey` of the string literal type `"student"`, and a variable `numberKey` of type `number`:

```
declare const school: School;
declare const studentKey: "student";
declare const numberKey: number;
```

Then you'd expect that `school[studentKey][numberKey]` would be a `Student`:

```
const student: Student = school[studentKey][numberKey]; // okay
```

And the type of `school[studentKey][numberKey]` is just `School["student"][number]`, which is what you're calling `Student`.

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWwAsIIAbOAbwCg44lMBbYALjgGcYpkBzAblocYAVwAmwFGxp06nMRJgB9BKLZJhjAEZoBMofJSKGzNp25J+ggL4BtALoCr1ajACeYPPhHiUcALwExKRkNgBEcj4woXY26lpoDtQA9Elwbh4E3gr+VMmpMhEKyqr0GtpQAil6hYbGrELmllVO1OLYZJhQeNgQSJwcQeRshCTkAm0dXXA9ffA1MADSwK5s4VkooePA7Z3dvf1x5UsrpfEV1DP988Pr8AHsgyHzxzGHaC98cFUQANaYrkA).

Of course it's more conventional to define `Student` first and then define `School` in terms of it, so unless you *need* to define `School` first and pull `Student` out of it, I'd follow [@Kokodoko's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56459173/2887218).

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you want to use generics? If your school interface also needs a student type you can declare another interface:

```
interface School {
    name: string;
    students: Student[];
}

interface Student {
    student_id: number;
    student_name: string;
}

let s:School = {
    name:"too cool for school",
    students: [
        { 
           student_id:3,
           student_name:"Joe"
        }
    ]
}
```